# wp_schedule_event not being run

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am having a difficult time trying to debug this. Basically trying to setup cron jobs inside a class of a plugin. I can see the event get scheduled with the correct time(viewed using Advance cron manager plugin) and everything but the event doesnt seem to fire. However the manual execution of the cron job seem to work(used the same plugin i mentioned above). Below is what I have:

```
class xx_import {

  const CRON_JOB_TITLE = 'automatic_import';

  private function __construct()
  {
    add_action( 'automatic_import', array( $this, 'import_feed' ) );
  }

  // Create a new cron job to import jobs
  public function setup_cron_job()
  {
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( self::CRON_JOB_TITLE );

    if( $timestamp == false )
    {
      wp_schedule_event( strtotime("+2 minutes"), 'daily', self::CRON_JOB_TITLE );
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you configured your PHP error log, what does this contain? Have you tested this plugin to view all WP Cron events? https://wordpress.org/plugins/cron-view/

Comment: too vague, as @David.J says use a debug file but you haven't included any code that init the class, the hooks to add the evt and the hook function you want to run.